# MySQL unknown column in "ON clause"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to find an answer to this but nothing seems to be relted to my issue.

I have three tables.

Images with columns src, description, id_image

img_link: id_img, id_art

articles: id_articles, title, content, date_create, news, id_author

To get realted images Im running this query:

```
SELECT images.src, 
    images.description 
FROM images 
LEFT JOIN articles ON articles.id_articles = img_link.id_art 
LEFT JOIN images lol ON img_link.id_img = lol.id_image
```

I get the error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'img_link.id_art' in 'on clause'

Any one know what may couse the error?

Comment: `img_link` comes from where? I don't see that table or alias anywhere in this query. That's why you get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need the following -

```
select
i.src,
i.description
from img_link il
left join images i on i.id_image = il.id_img
left join articles ar on ar.id_articles = il.id_art
```

Comment: Yep that's it, now I just need to take a look into your code and understand my mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant for your `FROM` clause to bring in the `img_link` table, rather than the `images table`, which you bring in via the second `LEFT JOIN`?  So, did you intend `FROM img_link`?

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood concept of using many to many relationships.